# C++ - save txt as html using fstream

Tags: c++, html, fstream

I am creating a simple program in that the user will be able to edit a .txt file created by the program and then the program should save that file as a .html document. I do not want to use any libraries whatsoever.

Creating the .txt file:

```
std::ofstream file("save.txt");
```

How should I do this without using any unneccesary extensions?

Comment: The only difference between a .txt file and a .html file is the file extension and that .html files use a stricter subset of words than .txt files. So, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all.  Sounds like all your program needs to do is change the extension from `.txt` to `.html`.

Comment: Thanks, Mooing Duck. Make that an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund: What is the user entering into the text file?  Please edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a new enough compiler:

```
std::ofstream("save.html") << std::ifstream("save.txt");
```

If you have an older compiler:

```
std::ifstream in("save.txt");
std::ofstream out("save.html");
out << in;
```

However, this makes a full and complete exact copy of the file with a different name.  I really recommend using an OS specific function call to simply rename the file, or even better, have the user just enter their data into the html file directly.

Comment: So if I were to make the user enter data to the html file directly; it's the same as if I were to enter the data into a txt file?

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund: If they're entering data into the txt file exactly in the html format, then yes.  If they aren't entering html data into the text file, then you have to tell us what's in the text file for us to answer this.  I've never heard of web page development using a txt file intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

There are three considerations in converting plain text to HTML. After the user has modified the plain text string:

1. Replace all line breaks (`\n`, `\r`, and `\n\r`) in your plain text string to HTML line break elements (`<br/>`). You can use the standard library [string replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) method to do this.
2. Wrap your modified text string in a standard HTML document structure (and add a title to the document): `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title> -- TITLE GOES HERE -- </title><body> -- TEXT GOES HERE -- </body></html>`.
3. Save the string as a text file ... just use the extension `.html` instead of `.txt`.

Comment: oh, converting raw text into html?  That's an interpretation that hadn't occured to me.  We'll have to get more details from teh user.